# How does one create a Play Module?

Tags: java, playframework

The Play framework documentation is kind of weak when it comes to module creation.

- How does one creates a Module ?
- I've read that large applications could be split across several modules, how ?
- What can/can't be done with a module ? (any access to low level api ?)
- Can a play module expose abstract JPA classes ?
- What's the best way to package a module ?
- How to deploy/distribute a play module ?

I think you get the idea... tell us all about Modules using the Playframework.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- How does one creates a Module ?

`play new-module`

- I've read that large applications could be split across several modules, how ?

Well you put components which functionality, for example security or user-management in a module. This module will be referred by you app.

- What can/can't be done with a module ? (any access to low level api ?)

There are no special things that can be done with a module, with can't be done in your app directly. So if you need a special feature only in 1 app you can program it there directly.

- Can a play module expose abstract JPA classes ?

There are no limits, you can declare there abstract-classes. Same as in a library.

- What's the best way to package a module ?

`play build-module`

- How to deploy/distribute a play module?

I mean in the discussion group there was plugin which enables you to run a private repository. If it was from general interest and you want to contribute it the whole community register it as a playframework.org, see the [guide](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1/modules#contributing).

[UPDATE] I copied some information about the `src`-folder from [google-group](http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/f3a86ff6425e1e61/65f775f44ca00118#65f775f44ca00118). The `src`-folder is for static utility-classes which are not play-specific and Play plugin. They will compiled as jars and put into the lib directory.

Niels

Comment: I see a slight difference between a module and a regular application. A module will have a folder hierarchy modulename/src in it lives a folder called play, and an empty file called play.plugins. Could you giv more details on those ?

Comment: play.plugins defines your own plugins which a priority. The src folder was new for me. I don't no for what it could be.