# How to extend the playframework?

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

Sometime it's necessary to extends a framework. Sometimes it's necessary to hook into the request/response lifecycle, for example for a parameter binding or to write a security module.
How could this be done in the playframework 1.x?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There are two ways to extend play 1.x. First you can write your own module. This is described in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120424/how-does-one-creates-a-play-module). This is useful if you want provide a library such as iText or provide a special authentication mechanism.

The second way is to write a `PlayPlugin`. This is often done in modules but it's not a necessary condition. To write a `PlayPlugin` requires two steps:

1. Write a class which extends the class `PlayPlugin` and override some of its [methods](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.1/play/PlayPlugin.html#method_summary), for example called `myPackage.MyPlugin`.
2. Register your plugin. This is done by creating a file named `play.plugins` and putting it into the classpath. The file must contain a line like `1003:myPackage.MyPlugin`.

The number defines the order in which the plugins are called. I recommend to use ids > 1000. If you want it to load before a framework plugin, look [here](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/1.1.x/framework/src/play.plugins) (The ids are valid since 1.1.1).

That's it. To get a feeling of what you can do with a Plugin see the [javadoc](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.1/play/PlayPlugin.html). You can hook into:

- The request/response-cycle
- The binding process
- application start/stop
- classloading

Unfortunately the javadoc documentation is minimal, but don't hesitate to look into the code of the playframework itself. It's easy to understand and gives you good ideas.

Comment: great answer, niels... should go straight to play-framework documentation

Comment: I've tried your method, but it seems like my plugin is loaded twice. My logs sais:

14:00:51,454 INFO  ~  -- beforeInvocation  controllers.MyPlugin@62d6a33f
14:00:51,454 INFO  ~  -- beforeInvocation  controllers.MyPlugin@7977afca

: two objects with different IDs

Comment: IF you use eclipse the file `play.plugins` is copied to the classes folder. If you start play from eclipse , play will find the file twice and load your Plugin twice.

Comment: Droping the "play.plugins" file in the "conf" folder solves the problem

Comment: Is the `play.plugins` file still required?

Comment: In play 1.x I think yes, but didn't tested the newest versions.

Comment: I tested (and looked into source code as I didn't find this post) in version 1.3 and play.plugins is still required.