# How to trim request parameters automatically in playframework

Tags: playframework, trim

Play will assign the parameters from request to action parameters, like:

```
public static void createArticle(String title, String content) {
}
```

But it won't trim them, so we usually to such code in the actions:

```
public static void createArticle(String title, String content) {
    if(title!=null) title = title.trim();
    if(content!=null) content = content.trim();
}
```

Is there any way to let play trim them automatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achive this with custom binders.
One way of doing would be this:

- Define acustom binder somewhere that trims the string
- Annotate every parameter you want to trim with `@As(binder=TrimmedString.class)`

  ```
  public class Application extends Controller {

      public static class TrimmedString implements TypeBinder<String> {
          @Override
          public Object bind(String name, Annotation[] annotations, String value, Class actualClass, Type genericType) throws Exception {
              if(value != null) {
                  value = value.trim();
              }
              return value;
          }
      }

      public static void index(
              @As(binder=TrimmedString.class) String s1,
              @As(binder=TrimmedString.class) String s2,
              @As(binder=TrimmedString.class) String s3) {
          render(s1, s2, s3);
      }
  }
  ```

If this is too verbose for you, simply use a `@Global` binder for String which checks for a custom `@Trim` or `@As('trimmed')` annotation. The TypeBinder already has all annotations available so this should be very easy to implement.

All this can be found in the documentation under [custom binding](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.1/controllers#custombinding).

Comment: this is helpful, thank you. But we need add the annotation to every fields, is inconvenient

Comment: If you really want to trim all strings just use @Global on a TypeBinder<String> and trim all of them.

Comment: I will try it later, then decide the best answer :)

Comment: TypeBinder is exactly made for that purpose, so I would prefer it over the @Before solution.
Also it seems quite complicated to me to implement this correctly in @Before. You don't know the type that the parameter is going to be in the action. Some types might rely on leading/trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do it would be to use object mappings instead, of individual String mappings.

So, you could create a class call Article, and create a setter that trims the content. Normally Play doesn't need you to create the setters, and they are autogenerated behind the scenes, but you can still use them if you have special processing.

```
public class Article {
    public String title;
    public String content;

    public void setTitle(String title) {
         this.title = title.trim();
    } 
    public void setContent(String content) {
         this.content = content.trim();
    }
}
```

You then need to pass the Article into your action method, rather than the individual String elements, and your attributes will be trimmed as part of the object mapping process.

Comment: this works, but not what I expected. I have to add a lot of methods to my models in this way. Hope there is simpler way. But thanks all the same

Comment: Your only other option is to create your own binder. A new answer shows how this can be done, or take a look at http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.1/controllers#custombinding

Answer (score 1):

You can write a [PlayPlugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699250/how-to-extend-the-playframework) and trim all parameters of the request.

Another possibility is to use the [Before-Interception](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.1/controllers#Before).

Comment: `@Before` can't be used here, since you can't get the parameters of other actions in a "before" method.

Comment: @Freewind: The [Request.params](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2.1/play/mvc/Http.Request.html#params) should be available.

Comment: thank you, trimming all the params in a global @Before action is the simplest way.