# trimming parameter before sending to controller in playframework

Tags: java, playframework

In my web app,I need to get a user entered number and process it in the controller.I need to make sure that the number is at least 14 digits in length.If the user enters 12 digits and then presses 'space' twice ,the validation should catch it.

I coded it like this

```
public static void processNumber(@Required @MinSize(value=14,message="min size is 14") String inputNumber){
if(validation.hasErrors()) {
    params.flash();
    validation.keep();
    ...
    }
```

}

However ,this doesn't work as I expected..Looks like ,I need to trim the input before it reaches the controller method.

Can someone suggest how to do this?

p.s:
More complex cases will be input like

'11  2233444444'
'1122334ad44444' etc,is there any validation to make sure that the input is a number and does not contain any alphabetic characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think a custom binder is going to give you what you are looking for, as you are not trying to modify the way the data is bound, but to validate what is in there. Therefore, I think what you are looking for is a custom validator.

See here for more information - http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2/validation#custom

But effectively, you can just use the @CheckWith annotation to specify which validator to use, and then in your validator, you can check that your trimmed string, contains no spaces, and no alpha characters etc.

Note, that the validator will not modify your input, so if you want to ignore trimmed data, then this will continue to stay in your data, so you can therefore modify (trim) it after it is validated, or you could do it using the custom binder as discussed in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if that could help you on what you want to do [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532838/how-to-trim-request-parameters-automatically-in-playframework)

I hope it helped.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a numeric value with at least 14 digits, one option would be:

```
public static void processNumber(@Required @Min(10000000000000) Long inputNumber)
```

Problems with this method:

- Maximum allowed number would be 9223372036854775807l
- It won't allow numbers starting with "0".

Some more options:

```
public static void processNumber(
    @Required @MinSize(value=14,message="min size is 14") String inputNumber){
validation.isTrue("inputNumber", !inputNumber.contains(" "));
if(validation.hasErrors()) {
```

Or even better:

```
public static void processNumber(
    @Required @MinSize(value=14,message="min size is 14") String inputNumber){
for(int i=0;i<inputNumber.length();i++) {
    validation.isTrue("inputNumber", Character.isDigit(inputNumber.charAt(i)))
if(validation.hasErrors()) {
```