# play! framework logging capabilities

Tags: logging, playframework

I want to do sufficient logging for all the incoming http requests from client side - including the http headers, parameters etc. Does Play! framework support that today? Or can I easily "plug-in" my logic to do that?

Another related question is that - instead of using a single log file holding the huge amount of log data over the time, I want to have one log file automatically generated every, let's say, 30 minutes. The log files will be given some sort of sequential numbers so I can go back in time to investigate issues happened few hours ago. Does play! framework support this kind of logging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a `PlayPlugin`, see [How to extend the playframework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699250/how-to-extend-the-playframework).

About the log-problem. Use your own category for this log-entries and send them to a [RollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to display this info as part of your template look at [The template implicit objects](http://playcheatsheet.appspot.com/show/ArtemMedeu/armed/play-cheatsheets) which you can simply output.

To log in different files every thirty minutes create a [log4j.configuration or log4j.xml](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) and setup a RollingFileAppender that rolls ever 30mn.