# Serving static files with authentication in the playframework

Tags: playframework

Is there an easy/build-in way to have a controller check if a connection is authorized to access a static file not the server (with the use of a DB lookup) and then provide access if needed.

There are large video files, and I want a) check if the user is allowed to access the file, and b) if the user is authorized I want to record that the video has been watched.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this.

#### The first and most elegant way of doing it would be using the Play Plugin feature.

You can find more info at [How to extend the playframework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699250/how-to-extend-the-playframework)
Here is the javadoc:
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2.3/play/PlayPlugin.html

#### The second would be to serve the files from a route

If the files are route/controller based then you can just protect them like you would any other controller.  Someone correct me if I'm wrong.

I would do something like (note this code has not been tested):

protect with `@With(Secure.class)`

```
public static void getImage() {
    File file = new File( "~/image.png" );
    response.contentType = "image/png";
    renderBinary( file );
}
```

Then the route

```
GET     /static/image1    Application.getImage
```

Or you could make it more elegant.

```
GET     /static/image/{fileName}   Application.getImage
GET     /static/image/{id}         Application.getImageById
```

and

```
   public static void getImage(String fileName) {
        File file = new File( "~/" + fileName );
        response.contentType = "image/png";
        renderBinary( file );
    }
```

Or take it further.

```
public static void getImage( String fileName, String username ) {
    File file = new File( "~/" + fileName );

    if ( file.exists() ) {
        User user = User.find( "byName", username ).fetch();
        user.watch = true;
        user.save();

        response.contentType = "image/png";
        renderBinary( file );
    }
}
```

Obviously you would need some trys and catches in there if the file didn't exist.

Good luck.