# Is it Possible to have more than one messages file in Play framework

Tags: internationalization, playframework

We have a site which will be used for two different clients. During first request the user will be asked to choose a client. Based on that text,labels and site content should be displayed.

Is it possible to have two messages file in Play framework and during session startup the messages file would be decided

As of my research we can have more than a file for each Locale, the messages will be get based on locale in the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this problem with below solution,

1. Created a class `MessagesPlugIn` which extends `play.i18n.MessagesPlugin`
2. Created a class `Messages` as like `play.i18n.Messages`
3. Had a static Map `messaagesByClientID` in `Messages.java`
4. Overridden `onApplicationStart()` in `MessagesPlugIn`
5. Loaded the Properties in `messaagesByClientID` as `locales` loaded in `play.i18n.MessagesPlugin`
6. Had a method `get()` in `Messages.java`, retrieve the property from `messaagesByClientID` based ClientId in the session. If the property is not available call `get()` in `play.i18n.Messages`

7.Created a Custom tag `il8nTag` and its used in HTML templates. `il8nTag` will invoke the methos in `Messages.get()`.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not supported at the moment. 
You can easily do that either in a plugin([Look at MessagesPlugin](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/i18n/MessagesPlugin.java) ) or even using a [bootstrap job](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/jobs) with the @onApplicationStartup annotation

```
// From MessagesPlugin.java

//default languange messages
VirtualFile appDM = Play.getVirtualFile("conf/messages");
if(appDM != null && appDM.exists()) {
    Messages.defaults.putAll(read(appDM));
}

static Properties read(VirtualFile vf) {
    if (vf != null) {
        return IO.readUtf8Properties(vf.inputstream());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I can this achive this when I load messages in Controllers. But how do I override the funtionality when the messages loaded in Templates using &{}. Please help me.

Comment: template messages should be working as well once you added them to Messages.defaults. Have you tried with no success?

Comment: Actually my requirement is,the application will have more than one property file with same keys,but values are different.It should able to retrieve a property from either of the file based on "ClientID" in the session.If I add it in default I couldn't find by session value.found another a solution.Created customMessagesPlugIn which extends MessagesPlugin and had HashMap within it,Load all the files in the map with client Id as key and Properties as value.A call for Messages.get(),will retreive the value based On client ID in the session.For templates I used custom tags to retrieve the message.

Comment: Thaks mericano1 for your support

Answer (score 1):

You can wrote you own [PlayPlugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699250/how-to-extend-the-playframework) and handle implement `play.PlayPlugin.getMessage(String, Object, Object...)`. Then you could choose the right file. The class [`play.i18n.Messages`](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/i18n/Messages.java) can be used as inspiration how to implement the method.

Comment: Thanks, Based on answers given this page I found the answer and posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own `Module` based on [`play.api.i18n.I18nModule`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/abae29831363cd1fe90d07584525cbd8c73b464c/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/i18n/Messages.scala#L549-556), but bound to your own implementation of `MessagesApi`, based on Play's [DefaultMessagesApi](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/abae29831363cd1fe90d07584525cbd8c73b464c/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/i18n/Messages.scala#L465) ([here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/abae29831363cd1fe90d07584525cbd8c73b464c/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/i18n/Messages.scala#L536-542) is the part defining the files to load)

Then in your `application.conf`, [disable Play's `play.api.i18n.I18nModule`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/be7e96a6935e2682b8b6934f90852aa6d0532482/framework/src/play/src/main/resources/reference.conf#L104-108) and enable your own module.